# Fixing third div under first div after scrolling down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to fix `#fixed_header_bottom` div right under `#fixed_header_top` div after scrolling **100px** down but failed to do so. `#fixed_header_middle` div obviously will appear and disappear when scrolling up and down and only `#fixed_header_top`, `#fixed_header_bottom` and `#body_block` will be visible when (for example scrolling down come to an end).

[JSFIDDLE is here](http://jsfiddle.net/h8H6N/)

In the second image, `#fixed_header_middle` disappeared completely but will start appearing when scrolling up.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: `.removeAttr('style');` is a heavy-handed way of getting rid of your fixed position.  I would make a class for the position and use `.addClass()` and `.removeClass()`

Comment: That's what I was looking for that part actually. I used it before but couldn't remember. Thanks.

Comment: See my answer below for a solution that uses `addClass()`/`removeClass()` and a placeholder div to avoid the jumpy problems.  Your IE issue is due to the version of jQuery you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to set a `top` style for your headers so they are in the correct position, you should think about a more robust way to do this.

Another way to consider doing this is to make a hidden clone of your bottom header.

Then, simply hide/show it when the scroll position is correct.  This method avoids any funny business with the scroll bar changing size and/or position as the element is taken in and out of the scrollable portion of the page (because the original is still there):

[<kbd>**JSFiddle Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/LbGP7/1/)

An even better way is to simply make a placeholder that you show/hide as the bottom header is fixed/un-fixed:

```
<div id="fixed_header_top">fixed_header_top</div>
<div id="fixed_header_middle">fixed_header_middle</div>
<div id="fixed_header_bottom">fixed_header_bottom</div>
<div id="fixed_placeholder">Shouldn't ever see me</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).bind("scroll", function (e) {
        if(!$('#fixed_header_bottom').hasClass('fixed')) {
            if ($(document).scrollTop() >= 100) {
                $('#fixed_placeholder').show();
                $('#fixed_header_bottom').addClass('fixed');
            }
        } else {
            if ($(document).scrollTop() < 100) {
                $('#fixed_placeholder').hide();
                $('#fixed_header_bottom').removeClass('fixed');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
#fixed_header_bottom, #fixed_placeholder {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #11DD55;
}
#fixed_placeholder {
    display: none;
}
.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50px;
}
```

[<kbd>**JSFiddle Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/28gWb/1/)

Comment: @MadMax I updated the jQuery versions in the above examples.  You were loading version 1.1 which did not handle `scrollTop()` well in IE.

Comment: Thanks. I'll use second JSF because it worked fine in all browsers however the first one didn't in "ill" IE.

Answer (score 1):

This code works as it should.

Your problem is that you didn't set any `top` property, so it stays on its original top position.

Same Fiddle with jQuery 1.8.3 (as 1.10 don't handle scrollTop() method for IE) ;): http://jsfiddle.net/h8H6N/4/

I added `top: 0;` to the header top, and `top: 50px;` to bottom header, assuming that's the render you're looking for.

Comment: FF-There is a jump, IE, SAFARI - didn't work, CHROME - works fine. Any fix to make cross browser and no jumping? Thanks

Comment: I'm on FF 26, Windows, works fine (like Chrome). I see the bug in IE, I'm on it.

Comment: The OP did put jQuery in, but it was version 1.10.1 loaded as an external resource.  The problem is that `scrollTop()` was not handled well for IE in earlier versions of jQuery.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see it. Good to know.

Comment: @enguerranws - Thanks for all help but it still has little jump in IE9. +1 anyway.